# Flex 4.6 Mobile Horizontal List: Reload itemRenderer

Tags: android, actionscript-3, apache-flex, mobile, flex4

I have one list which is having the layout set to horizontal display.

```
<s:List id="pagedList"
        width="100%" height="100%"
        verticalScrollPolicy="off" horizontalScrollPolicy="on"
        pageScrollingEnabled="true"
        itemRenderer="views.component.renderer.pageListItemRenderer"
        skinClass="views.component.skin.PagedListSkin"
        dataProvider="{acPages}"
        scrollSnappingMode="center"
        interactionMode="touch"
        useVirtualLayout="true">
            <s:layout>
                <s:TileLayout orientation="rows" requestedRowCount="1"
                              columnWidth="{pagedList.width}" rowHeight="{pagedList.height}" 
                              verticalGap="0" horizontalGap="0" />
                </s:layout>
</s:List>
```

The dataProvider for the list is

```
[Bindable]
private var acPages:ArrayCollection = 
    new ArrayCollection( [
        {status:"Approved", method:"findRange(0,10)"},
        {status:"Pending", method:"findRange(10,20)"},
        {status:"Draft", method:"findRange(20,30)"},
        {status:"Ready", method:"findRange(30,40)"},
        {status:"Cancelled", method:"findRange(40,50)"},
        {status:"Recommended", method:"findRange(50,60)"},
        {status:"Resubmitted", method:"findRange(60,70)"}
]);
```

And finally the itemRenderer

```
<fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
override public function set data(value:Object):void 
            {
                super.data = value;

                if (value== null)
                    return;

                if (data.status)
                    mss.loadDgrid(data.method);
            }
    ]]>
    </fx:Script>

<s:Group width="100%" height="100%">
        <s:layout>
            <s:VerticalLayout gap="0" verticalAlign="middle" horizontalAlign="center" paddingBottom="30"/>
        </s:layout>
        <s:Group width="100%" contentBackgroundColor="0x000001">
            <s:layout>
                <s:HorizontalLayout horizontalAlign="center" verticalAlign="middle"/>
            </s:layout>
            <s:Label fontWeight="bold" text="&lt;" paddingLeft="20"/>
            <s:Spacer width="100%"/>
            <s:Label fontWeight="bold" text="{data.status}"/>
            <s:Spacer width="100%"/>
            <s:Label fontWeight="bold" text="&gt;" paddingRight="20"/>
        </s:Group>

        <s:DataGrid id="dgTaskGrid"
                    width="100%" height="100%"
                    verticalScrollPolicy="on"
                    dataProvider="{mss.dataProvider}">
            <s:columns>
                <s:ArrayList>
                    <s:GridColumn headerText="Application ID" dataField="phId" />
                    <s:GridColumn headerText="Status" dataField="phAppStatus" />
                </s:ArrayList>
            </s:columns>
        </s:DataGrid>
    </s:Group>
```

What you can see is that the list will be displaying 7 pages based on the `acPages ArrayCollection` and user can swipe left-right on the list to get to the next/previous page. Each page will be having the DataGrid and should load their own respective content. For example, the Approved page will display their own data using the `data.method` assigned on `acPages`. The `mss.loadDgrid` will then send a `HTTPRequest` to the webservice and returns the result.

Currently, what is happening, the list will first display the Approved data correctly, once I swipe to the left to reveal the next page(Pending page), the page will render well with the required data. But when I swipe back to the previous page (Approved page), the DataGrid is displaying the data from the pending page. I was thinking that it should reload back but that is not the case. This apply to the rest of the pages.

I tried the `useVirtualLayout` set to `false` and `true` but seems nothing worked out. I also had overide the `set Data` function as well as listening to `dataChange()` of the `itemRenderer` but still it doesn't reload.

What I want now is on each swipe, the `itemRenderer` will refresh and gets the desired data.

I am a newbie on Flex, so could be the approach I used is wrong. Looking forward for your help.

Thanks,
Jason

Answer (score 0):

This is the itemrenderer refresh issue.  You may have a look on the following:

[Invalidating a Spark List Component to Redraw All Item Renderers](http://blog.9mmedia.com/?p=709)

What is the reason to put all the data in acPages arraycollection?  Maybe, you can create 7 arraycollection to hold the data, and then assign it to acPages when it is necessary.

Comment: I still can't get it done. Basically what I want to achieve is like what Android's ViewPager component do.